# iOS app under Spanish store not US

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have an app which is published to AppStore. Name of app is '**bucketnote**'.

On iTunesConnect if I tap to *Additional Information - View on App Store* it brings me to official link which is under US store: [bucketnote US store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bucketnote/id1155980865?ls=1&mt=8)

Now, we did some user testing, and if I tap in google for my app, it brings me to ES store: [bucketnote ES store](https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/bucketnote/id1155980865?mt=8)

We want to bring the user to US store.

Any idea how is possible that?

Thanks in advance

PS: Attached screenshots:
[image: Search for App ID]
[image: Search for App Name]

Comment: All places where we set language, we set it to US. Nothing with ES. Thanks a lot

Comment: which country set in your itunes account ?

Comment: @ravi.p its US in all places

Comment: Any update for this ? can anyone help here? Thanks